# How to represent date array in java script for highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to represent data include dates on highcharts dynamically(get from database) how can I do this?
assume this is my static data

```
series: [{
       data: [[Date.parse('7/7/2017'),222],[Date.parse('9/9/2019'),333]],
       pointStart: Date.parse('7/7/2017'),
       pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
}]
});
```

how can I create this array([[Date.parse('7/7/2017'),222],[Date.parse('9/9/2019'),333]]) in java script dynamically and how can I pass it to series element in highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, i have prepare chart for you, **from your data.**

```js
var initialData = [{
    "name": "sales",    
     pointStart: Date.parse('7/7/2017'),
     pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, 
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    data: [[Date.parse('8/7/2017'),222],[Date.parse('9/7/2017'),333],[Date.parse('11/7/2017'),333]]}];
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'area',
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        showFirstLabel: true,
        showLastLabel: true,
        endOnTick: true,
       // second: '%H:%M:%S',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        
            day: '%d. %b',
            month: '%b \'%y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', this.value);
            }
        }
        //,tickInterval : null
    },
    yAxis: {
    },
   
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            fillOpacity: .5,
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            },
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
  
    series: initialData
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply first, but please I need to pass this data dynamically(in variable)
assume that i have this data([[('8/7/2017'),222],[('9/7/2017'),333],[('11/7/2017'),333]]}]) in json string how can i store it in array variable and then pass it to data element in series.

Comment: Your data example is not in JSON format, fixed syntax: `[["8/7/2017",222],["9/7/2017",333],["11/7/2017",333]]`. For live data you can get your data from server at specific interval using get request from client side [link](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data), also if you want to update your data on the fly you can use `series[x].setData()` method: [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData).

Comment: i have took your data format from asked question for your convenient

Comment: I solved it with 2 dimension array but there are another problem, date appear in the tooltip in the chart is less than than date given in the array by one day,why?

Comment: I have updated answer, but actually tool tip is comming right if you can see the data of x and y axis inside chart instead of given array.